# cannot read property of map undefined react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a newbie react learner and here trying to make an api call to display list of weather details(for test case I am trying to get "app_max_temp") but I am getting error as "cannot read property of map undefined at SearchCity(SearchCity.js:29)" .I have tried that url in postman and works absolutely fine giving  response data. I have my code below. I can't figure out what is wrong and how to solve it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```js
import React,{useState} from 'react';

export default function SearchCity(){

    const[query,setQuery] = useState('');
    const[weatherResponse,setWeatherResponse] = useState([]);

    const searchCity = async (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        const api_key ="YourApiKey";
        const url = `https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/forecast/daily?city=${query}&key=${api_key}`;
        try{
            const res = await fetch(url);
            const data = await res.json();
            console.log(data.results);
            setWeatherResponse(data.results);
        }
        catch(error){
            console.error(error);
        }

    }

    return(
        <>
            <form className="form" onSubmit={searchCity}>
                <label className="cityTitle" htmlFor="query">City Name : </label>
                <input type="text" value={query} name="query" onChange={(e)=>setQuery(e.target.value)} />
                <button className="btnSearch" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>  
                {weatherResponse.map(res=>(
                <p>{res.app_max_temp}</p>
                )
                 )}
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: What do you see in `console.log(data.results);`?

Comment: It doesn't compile , throws that map undefined error

Comment: map undefined should be a runtime error, not a compile time error.  Syntax errors would be the type of error to prevent compile or fail before running

Comment: @Milan - That's what you get after submitting the form because there is no results entry in `data` and since you're assigning undefined to your state the `.map` part throws an error.

Answer (score 1):

[Weatherbit 16 Day Forecast API Documentation](https://www.weatherbit.io/api/weather-forecast-16-day)
[Weatherbit 16 Day Forecast Swagger UI](https://www.weatherbit.io/api/swaggerui/weather-api-v2#!/1632day324732daily32Forecast/get_forecast_daily_city_id_city_id)

The API returns those values in property data, not result:

```
        console.log(data.data);
        setWeatherResponse(data.data);
```

Make sure you have a proper API key (don't post it on here of course).

Comment: Here is the [documentation](https://www.weatherbit.io/api/weather-forecast-16-day).

Comment: hey @Milan please consider marking it as a right answer if it solved your issue.

Comment: @Ebdulmomen66 how do you mean? I already marked it but it won't show until I have 15 reputations.

Comment: Wow was there really a restriction like that?

Comment: @user120242 yea, unfortunately there is. And it showed now. Thanks to stack overflow team.